# DTS exchange tool

Tags: ssis, dts

We have a large collection of DTS packages that need to be converted to SSIS as part of SQL upgrade?. How effective is this tool compared to the wizard?. Some of the functionality that is available in DTS

Import/Export
SQL operations
Copying/Renaming/moving  files
Activex scripts (Not complex, most of the business functionality is in Stored procedures). Any help in sharing documentation or web links or any insight is well appreciated.

Comment: What is the tool you are trying to compare to the DTS > SSIS migration wizard?

Comment: yes, I am trying to compare with the wizard to see the cost benefits

Comment: You misunderstand me. What is the name of the tool? Can you provide a link for it?

Comment: the tool name is in the subject line. DTS exchange by pragmatic works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a full comparison here: http://www.pragmaticworks.com/products/business-intelligence/dtsxchange/DTSxChange-vs-MSWizard.htm

At a high-level, the existing Microsoft wizard does not handle some common tasks like Dynamic Properties Task. It also doesn't handle things like ODBC or all the flat file conditions. With the DTS xChange tool, it will migrate pretty much all conditions, re-engineer the logging and auditing framework of the package and turn on some of the new features in SSIS. It also includes BI xPress, which will help migrate ActiveX Scripts post-migration with code snippets.